# This->DataContext not working in uwp c++/cf in visual studio 2019 in C++

Tags: c++, uwp, visual-studio-2019, uwp-xaml, datacontext

I am using UWP to create an app for a server application and I have made a class serverclass.h in c++ in which I have a string output. Now I want to print this output in a textbox in xaml. I have attached the codes below. When I'm using this->DataContext=ser; it is giving me an error:"function Windows::UI::Xaml::FrameworkElement::DataContext::set cannot be called with the given argument list".
What is the problem here?

mainpage.xaml.cpp

```
serverclass ser;

MainPage::MainPage()
{
    
    
    InitializeComponent();
    this->DataContext = ser;
}



void App1::MainPage::Button_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    ser.output = "hey";
    ser.connect();
    
}
```

serverclass.h

```
class serverclass
{
public:

    
    string output;

}

"mainpage.xaml"

<TextBox Text="{Binding output}" Height="50" FontSize="30px">
                
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print your string output in a textbox in xaml, you could use data binding referring to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart) and [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/XamlBind/cpp/MyUserControl1.xaml.h).

For the scenario mentioned by you, you could check the following code:
serverclass.h

```
namespace YourAppName{//Put the serverclass into the namespace
public ref class serverclass sealed : Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private:
    Platform::String^ output;
public:
    virtual event Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler^ PropertyChanged;
    serverclass()
    {  }
    property Platform::String^ Output {
        Platform::String^ get() { return output; }
        void set(Platform::String^ value) {
            if (output != value)
            {
                output = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventArgs("Output"));
            }
        }
    };
};
}
```

MainPage.xaml.h

```
public ref class MainPage sealed
{
public:
       MainPage();
       property serverclass^ Ser {
             serverclass^ get() { return ser; }
             void set(serverclass^ value) {
                    ser = value;
             }
      }
   private:
          serverclass^ ser;
          void Button_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, 
          Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e);
   };
```

MainPage.xaml.cpp

```
MainPage::MainPage()
{
       InitializeComponent();
       this->ser = ref new serverclass();
       ser->Output = "world";
       this->DataContext = ser;
}
void DataContextSample::MainPage::Button_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
       ser->Output = "hello";
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{x:Bind Ser.Output,Mode=TwoWay}"  Width="100" Height="30" Margin="10"/>
    <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="click me"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: The above code is just printing "world" not "Hello".

Comment: The initial value of `ser->Output` is `world`, and the value will be changed as `hello` when you click the button which is used to test the **TwoWay** binding.
If you click on the button and the text of TextBox is not changed, you could add a breakpoint at the line of code `if(output!=value)`  in `Output` property’s `set()` method to view if the  `PropertyChanged` is triggered.